# When I call Frontend controller action is called but after success it sets admin_in url

Tags: magento-1.9, url, controllers, frontend

Currently i have faced one issue. when i call frontend controller from this url
**project/index.php/become-a-ditributor.html**

front controller action call successfully but after success my url show **admin_** in url. i dont know what is problem.

config.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <DD_Distributor>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </DD_Distributor>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <distributor>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>DD_Distributor</module>
                    <frontName>distributor</frontName>
                </args>
            </distributor>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <distributor>
                    <file>distributor.xml</file>
                </distributor>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <distributor>
                <class>DD_Distributor_Helper</class>
            </distributor>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <distributor>
                <class>DD_Distributor_Block</class>
            </distributor>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <distributor>
                <class>DD_Distributor_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>distributor_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </distributor>
            <distributor_mysql4>
                <class>DD_Distributor_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>        
                    <distributor>
                        <table>distributor</table>
                    </distributor>
                </entities>
            </distributor_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <distributor_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>DD_Distributor</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </distributor_setup>
            <distributor_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </distributor_write>
            <distributor_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </distributor_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <distributor>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <DD_Distributor after="Mage_Adminhtml">DD_Distributor_Adminhtml</DD_Distributor>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </distributor>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <distributor module="distributor">
                <title>Distributor</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <distributor module="distributor">
                        <title>Manage Distributor</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/distributor</action>
                    </distributor>
                </children>
            </distributor>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <distributor translate="title" module="distributor">
                            <title>Distributor</title>
                            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <distributor translate="title">
                                    <title>Manage Distributor</title>
                                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                </distributor>
                            </children>
                        </distributor>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <distributor>
                    <file>distributor.xml</file>
                </distributor>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <adminhtml_distributor_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="distributor/adminhtml_distributor" name="distributor" />
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_distributor_index>
</layout>
```

[image]

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: what you are giving in redirect url in **Controller** ?

Comment: $this->_redirect('*/distributor/index/');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get what is problem here but you should use this as **admin router configuration**

```
   <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <DD_Distributor after="Mage_Adminhtml">DD_Distributor_Adminhtml</DD_Distributor>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

change your action from

```
<action>admin_distributor/adminhtml_distributor</action>
```

to

```
<action>adminhtml/distributor</action>
```

in xml layout this will be

```
<adminhtml_distributor_index>
```

update config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <DD_Distributor>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </DD_Distributor>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <distributor>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>DD_Distributor</module>
                    <frontName>distributor</frontName>
                </args>
            </distributor>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <distributor>
                    <file>distributor.xml</file>
                </distributor>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <distributor>
                <class>DD_Distributor_Helper</class>
            </distributor>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <distributor>
                <class>DD_Distributor_Block</class>
            </distributor>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <distributor>
                <class>DD_Distributor_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>distributor_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </distributor>
            <distributor_mysql4>
                <class>DD_Distributor_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>        
                    <distributor>
                        <table>distributor</table>
                    </distributor>
                </entities>
            </distributor_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <distributor_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>DD_Distributor</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </distributor_setup>
            <distributor_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </distributor_write>
            <distributor_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </distributor_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <DD_Distributor after="Mage_Adminhtml">DD_Distributor_Adminhtml</DD_Distributor>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <distributor module="distributor">
                <title>Distributor</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <distributor module="distributor">
                        <title>Manage Distributor</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/distributor</action>
                    </distributor>
                </children>
            </distributor>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <distributor translate="title" module="distributor">
                            <title>Distributor</title>
                            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <distributor translate="title">
                                    <title>Manage Distributor</title>
                                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                </distributor>
                            </children>
                        </distributor>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <distributor>
                    <file>distributor.xml</file>
                </distributor>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: code is work but my backend not work its redirect to 404

Comment: @AjayPatel you have to change all url with `adminhtml/controllername/action` same go with layout `adminhtml_controllername_action`

Comment: No. Can you please tell me how do this?? DD_Distributor_Adminhtml_DistributorController my current controller name

Comment: @AjayPatel i added the example how to do that

Comment: No luck :( with this.

Comment: @AjayPatel did you remove this code `<admin>
    <routers>
      <distributor>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>DD_Distributor</module>
          <frontName>admin_distributor</frontName>
        </args>
      </distributor>
    </routers>
  </admin>` and remove **var/cache** folder too also use the exit(); in you indexAction() to check going to correct url or not?

Comment: yes. i have do this. but still got 404

Comment: controller is not call

Comment: @AjayPatel you didn't change the `<menu>
      <distributor module="distributor">
        <title>Distributor</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <distributor module="distributor">
            <title>Manage Distributor</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>admin_distributor/adminhtml_distributor</action>
          </distributor>
        </children>
      </distributor>
    </menu>` as i mention in answer `<action>adminhtml/distributor</action>`

Comment: I have updated only layout edited question not config

Comment: i asked to change the url in admin menu too also you don't change the router too how this will work. change all the change then feedback me. change that too so i can look what the problem here

Comment: Check i have updated my question. i have set all your intruction

Comment: still admin url going to 404 page?

Comment: yes. i dont know whats is problem with this code.. :(

Comment: now i got only blank page at backend

Comment: i have already remove exit but backend menu are display content part is empty. controller work well

Comment: admin/distributor/index/key/ae4cb2bfe89ab68ddc2469af4a855e26/

Comment: i want to display grid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52123/discussion-between-qaisar-satti-and-ajay-patel).